# Tidal Workload automation : Fault Monitor lost the connect with Master

Tags: tidal-scheduler

02/01 21:55:41:394[197:RdOnly-13]: (mem=2286410344/2508193792) FTNodeMessageHandler: Connection is lost from node

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Fault Monitor service on the Fault Monitor server. That resolved the issue.